# Probable existence of an almost integer contained in a limit

Tags: limits, polynomials, gamma-function, constants

I found this almost integer in studying the limit :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\Gamma\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\Gamma\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-x^3=-\infty$$

Well my goal was to find a constant such that :

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\Gamma\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\Gamma\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-x^{\alpha}=constant$$

It appears that the constant in question have the following bound :

$$2.9999999990001<\alpha<2.999999999001$$

Found numerically obviously .

For the LHS the limit goes to infinity and with the RHS the limit goes to the opposite.

Now I'm not able to prove anything and curiously I didn't found anything on the websites .

So :
Is the second limit viable ?
Is this almost integer well know ?
Can we hope to find a closed form ?

Comment: I can turn this into an answer if you want, but here are some observations. Let $G(x)$ denote $\Gamma(\sin^2(1/x))\Gamma(\sin(1/x))$. Using usual asymptotics, one has $G(x)\sim x^3 - \gamma x^2 +(\frac{1}{2}-\gamma +\frac{\gamma ^2}{2}+\frac{\pi ^2}{12})x$, in the sense that $G(x) - \text{above}\to \text{constant}$ as $x\to\infty$. This implies that $\lim G(x)-x^3$ doesn't exist but that $\lim G(x)/x^3=1$. Not sure where these numerical bounds came from but I don't think they're right.

Comment: @FearfulSymmetry Thanks to comment and feel free to answer .The numerical bound are obtained with Wolfram alpha wich guess the negative or positive divergence.:-)

Comment: No more symmetry ? (joke). All calculations done with unlimited precision (including for $\alpha$ converted to a rational number).

Comment: No, given that this product of Gammas is $\sim x^3$, no difference with $x^\alpha$ , $\alpha<3$ is bounded. How did you use WA to reach this conclusion ? [presumably, by *constant* you mean *finite*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I do not want to play trouble fete !*

When $x$ is large, if
$$f(x)=\Gamma\left(\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)\Gamma\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$$ the expansion to $O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is
$$f(x)=x^3-\gamma  x^2+\frac{1}{12} \left(6 (\gamma -1)^2+\pi ^2\right) x+\left(-\frac{\zeta
   (3)}{3}-\frac{1}{12} \gamma  \left(4+2 (\gamma -6) \gamma +\pi
   ^2\right)\right)$$ then no problem with the first statement.

Using $x=10^k$ and computing for $\alpha$ equal to the average of the two given bounds ($\alpha$ being a rational number), some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & f\left(10^k\right)-10^{\alpha k} \\
 4 & -5.77032\times 10^7 \\
 5 & -5.76056\times 10^9 \\
 6 & -5.63407\times 10^{11} \\
 7 & -4.16123\times 10^{13} \\
 8 & +1.26384\times 10^{16} \\
 9 & +2.01347\times 10^{19} \\
 10 & +2.29555\times 10^{22} \\
 11 & +2.53087\times 10^{25} \\
 12 & +2.76153\times 10^{28} \\
 13 & +2.99171\times 10^{31} \\
 14 & +3.22185\times 10^{34} \\
 15 & +3.45198\times 10^{37} \\
 16 & +3.68211\times 10^{40} \\
 17 & +3.91224\times 10^{43} \\
 18 & +4.14237\times 10^{46} \\
 19 & +4.37251\times 10^{49} \\
 20 & +4.60264\times 10^{52}
\end{array}
\right)$$

There is nothing strange in this table. As Newton iterates show below, it exists a $k$ such that, for this specific value of $\alpha$
$$f\left(10^k\right)=10^{\alpha k}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & k_n \\
 0 & 7.5000000 \\
 1 & 7.5224059 \\
 2 & 7.5229715 \\
 3 & 7.5229719
\end{array}
\right)$$

In a second step, I computed
$$g(k)=f(10^{20})-\big[10^{20}\big]^{3-10^{-k}}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & g(k) \\
 2 & 3.69043\times 10^{59} \\
 3 & 4.50074\times 10^{58} \\
 4 & 4.59458\times 10^{57} \\
 5 & 4.60411\times 10^{56} \\
 6 & 4.60506\times 10^{55} \\
 7 & 4.60517\times 10^{54} \\
 8 & 4.60500\times 10^{53} \\
 9 & 4.55947\times 10^{52} \\
 10 & 4.60517\times 10^{51} \\
 11 & 4.60517\times 10^{50} \\
 12 & 4.60505\times 10^{49} \\
 13 & 4.60644\times 10^{48} \\
 14 & 4.60109\times 10^{47} \\
 15 & 4.60287\times 10^{46}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Dear Claude first thanks a lot ! I see in your calculations the problem is when $7<k<8$.What is your conclusion about it ? :-)

Comment: @ErikSatie. Edited and more has been added.

Comment: @ErikSatie. I suggest you plot $$\frac{\log \left(\Gamma \left(\sin \left(10^{-k}\right)\right) \Gamma \left(\sin
   ^2\left(10^{-k}\right)\right)\right)}{\log \left(10^k\right)}-3$$